# PowerMock - NPE on @PrepareForTest

Tags: java, powermock

Problem: The instrumentation class in PowerMock isn't being initialized.  I'm loading the library through the @Rule annotation.  I've got the VM argument in place: 
-javaagent:project_path/libs/powermock-module-javaagent-1.5.jar

When I walk through with the debugger, PowerMockAgent#premain gets called and the instrumentation object gets set, but when it's called during the test setup, the instrumentation object is null, throwing the error below.

Why is the instrumentation variable not keeping it's value between when PowerMockAgent#premain is called and when PowerMockClassRedefiner.redefine calls it?

**Instrumentation gets set correctly here on load:**

```
  private static void initialize(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws IOException {
    instrumentation = inst;
    inst.addTransformer(new DefinalizingClassTransformer(), false);
    inst.addTransformer(classTransformer, true);
}
```

**But when called again from @PrepareForTest({ Logger.class }), is null**

```
public class PowerMockClassRedefiner {

public static void redefine(Class<?> cls) {
    if(cls == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class to redefine cannot be null");
    }

    PowerMockAgent.getClasstransformer().setClassesToTransform(Arrays.asList(cls.getName()));

    try {            
        PowerMockAgent.instrumentation().retransformClasses(cls);
    } catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to redefine class "+cls.getName(), e);
    }
}
```

Resulting in error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to redefine class com.testapp.Logger
at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockClassRedefiner.redefine(PowerMockClassRedefiner.java:33)
at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockClassRedefiner.redefine(PowerMockClassRedefiner.java:42)
at com.testapp.testFramework.PowerMockRuleAgentSetup.redefine(PowerMockRuleAgentSetup.java:29)
at com.testapp.testFramework.PowerMockRuleAgentSetup.initialize(PowerMockRuleAgentSetup.java:19)
at com.testapp.testFramework.PowerMockOverriderRule.apply(PowerMockOverriderRule.java:19)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.withMethodRules(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:341)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.withRules(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:330)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:248)
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.methodBlock(RobolectricTestRunner.java:287)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockClassRedefiner.redefine(PowerMockClassRedefiner.java:31)
... 22 more
```

Here's my test setup:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Logger.class })  // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR GETS THROWN
public class LoggerTest {
@Rule public PowerMockOverriderRule rule = new PowerMockOverriderRule();
public LoggerConfig config;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    config = mock(LoggerConfig.class);
}
```

UPDATE:
Removing the @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class) fixes the problem, but isn't an option for my project. (It's an Android project).

Comment: Did you try  `@Rule public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();` as stated in the [PowerMock Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule)?

Comment: Yes, but this static block in the PowerMockRule class prevents that from getting anywhere off the ground: `static {
        if(PowerMockRule.class.getClassLoader() != ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("PowerMockRule can only be used with the system classloader but was loaded by "+PowerMockRule.class.getClassLoader());
        }
        PowerMockAgent.initializeIfPossible();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to ask but why would you even want to mock a Logger class? If you want to ensure that the output is logged to the console you can wrap a logger in an abstraction that you can mock.

```
class LogWraper {
   void someMethod() {
     logger.log()
   }
}
```

and then you can create a mock of your FooWraper. No need to use Powermock at all...

Comment: fwiw, `LoggerConfig` was a wrapper for the Android `Log` class.